# Align enumerate and align

Tags: align, enumerate

I wanted this:

[image]

Hence my solution was

```
Solution:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item 
\leavevmode\\[-2.75\baselineskip]
\begin{flalign*}
\mbox{US}\$10 &= \mbox{S}\$10\times1.33&\\
&= \mbox{S}\$13.30&
\end{flalign*}
\item 
\leavevmode\\[-2.75\baselineskip]
\begin{flalign*}
\mbox{S}\$1 &= \mbox{US}\$1 \div1.33&\\
&= \mbox{US}\$0.75188&\\
\mbox{S}\$20 &= \mbox{US}\$20\times0.75188&\\
&= \mbox{US}\$15.04\mbox{ (2DP)}&
\end{flalign*}
\end{enumerate}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this? As I need to guess about the spacing to shift up the equation beside (a) using [-2.75\baselineskip].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure whether this will qualify to be elegant but looks better for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Solution:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item $
\begin{aligned}[t]
\text{US}\$10 &= \text{S}\$10\times1.33\\
&= \text{S}\$13.30
\end{aligned}
$
\item $
\begin{aligned}[t]
\text{S}\$1 &= \text{US}\$1 \div1.33\\
&= \text{US}\$0.75188\\
\text{S}\$20 &= \text{US}\$20\times0.75188&\\
&= \text{US}\$15.04\text{ (2DP)}
\end{aligned}
$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought the \leavevmode\\[-2.75\baselineskip] was quite ugly as I needed to guess how much spacing to shift up the equation to align to (a).

Comment: Any particular reason why \text should be used instead of \mbox?

Comment: @Eugene `\text` is capable of detecting fonts (properties) in the surroundings, `\mbox` is not.

Comment: Just one more question, I was trying to search for more information about the aligned package but could not find any so far, most of the Google results gave align instead of aligned.

Comment: @Eugene Search in this site or `texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt/terminal to get the `amsmath` manual.

Comment: the `=` signs in the second item aren't aligned with those in the first.  this can be done easily, if desired, taking advantage of the fact that the longest bit on the left-hand side is shorter by just the `U`.  then, enter that as `\phantom{U}\text{S}\$20` and *all* the `=` signs will line up.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using a regular `array` aligned at the `[t]`op. Using some `\phantom`s and over`lap`ping you can also align across the enumeration:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumitem,array}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{document}

Solution:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item 
  $\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}}
    \mbox{US}\$10 &= \mbox{S}\$10 \times 1.33 \\
                  &= \mbox{S}\$13.30
  \end{array}$

  \item 
  $\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}>{{}}l@{}}
     \phantom{\mbox{US}\$10}\llap{\mbox{S}\$1} &= \mbox{US}\$1 \div 1.33 \\
                  &= \mbox{US}\$0.75188 \\
     \mbox{S}\$20 &= \mbox{US}\$20 \times 0.75188 \\
                  &= \mbox{US}\$15.04 \mbox{ (2DP)}
  \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```